# Copying GHC ByteArray# to Ptr

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to write the following function:

```
memcpyByteArrayToPtr :: 
     ByteArray# -- ^ source
  -> Int -- ^ start
  -> Int -- ^ length
  -> Ptr a -- ^ destination
  -> IO ()
```

The behavior should be to internally use `memcpy` to copy the contents of a `ByteArray#` to the `Ptr`. There are two techniques I have seen for doing something like this, but it's difficult for me to reason about their safety.

The first is found in the [memory](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory) package. There is an auxiliary function [withPtr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memory-0.13/docs/src/Data-ByteArray-Bytes.html#withPtr) defined as:

```
data Bytes = Bytes (MutableByteArray# RealWorld)

withPtr :: Bytes -> (Ptr p -> IO a) -> IO a
withPtr b@(Bytes mba) f = do
    a <- f (Ptr (byteArrayContents# (unsafeCoerce# mba)))
    touchBytes b
    return a
```

But, I'm pretty sure that this is only safe because the only way to construct `Bytes` is by using a smart constructor that calls `newAlignedPinnedByteArray#`. [An answer given to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432589/1405768) and the [docs for `byteArrayContents#`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:byteArrayContents-35-) indicate that it is only safe when dealing with pinned `ByteArray#`s. In my situation, I'm dealing with the `ByteArray#`s that the `text` library [uses internally](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Array.html), and they are not pinned, so I believe this would be unsafe.

The second possibility I've stumbled across is in `text` itself. At the bottom of the [Data.Text.Array source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/src/Data-Text-Array.html), there is an ffi function `memcpyI`:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "_hs_text_memcpy" memcpyI
  :: MutableByteArray# s -> CSize -> ByteArray# -> CSize -> CSize -> IO ()
```

This is backed by the following c code:

```
void _hs_text_memcpy(void *dest, size_t doff, const void *src, size_t soff, size_t n)
{
  memcpy(dest + (doff<<1), src + (soff<<1), n<<1);
}
```

Because its a part of `text`, I trust that this is safe. It looks like it's dangerous because is that it's getting a memory location from an unpinned `ByteArray#`, the very thing that the `byteArrayContents#` documentation warns against. I suspect that it's ok because the ffi call is marked as unsafe, which I think prevents the GC from moving the `ByteArray#` during the ffi call.

That's the research I've done far. So far, my best guess is that I can just copy what's been done in `text`. The big difference would be that, instead of passing in `MutableByteArray#` and `ByteArray#` as the two pointers, I would be passing in `ByteArray#` and `Ptr a` (or maybe `Addr#`, I'm not sure which of those you typically use with the ffi).

Is what I have suggested safe? Is there a better way that would allow me to avoid using the ffi? Is there something in `base` that does this? Feel free to correct any incorrect assumptions I've made, and thanks for any suggestions or guidance.

Comment: `copyByteArrayToAddr# :: ByteArray# -> Int# -> Addr# -> Int# -> State# s -> State# s` looks promising. The documentation seems to be missing some words, though, making it a bit unclear when it's valid.

"Copy a range of the ByteArray. The ByteArray must fully contain the specified ranges, but this is not checked. The Addr# must not point into the ByteArray were pinned), but this is not checked either."

Comment: Ah, that's just a Haddock problem. The source says "The Addr# must not   point into the MutableByteArray# (e.g. if the MutableByteArray# were
 pinned), but this is not checked either."

Comment: Excellent. That seems like it should be safe then. If you would like convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. If not, I'll convert it tomorrow and accept it.

Comment: FWIW, your understanding of what's going on is correct also.

Comment: @ReidBarton Thanks! Always nice to double check assumptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
copyByteArrayToAddr# :: ByteArray# -> Int# -> Addr# -> Int# -> State# s -> State# s
```

looks like the right primop. You just need to be sure not to try to copy it into memory it occupies. So you should probably be safe with

```
copyByteArrayToPtr :: ByteArray# -> Int -> Ptr a -> Int -> ST s ()
copyByteArrayToPtr ba (I# x) (Ptr p) (I# y) = ST $ \ s ->
  (# copyByteArrayToAddr# ba x p y s, () #)
```

Unfortunately, the documentation gives me no clue what each `Int#` is supposed to mean, but I imagine you can figure that out through trial and segfault.

Comment: From its use in `Data.ByteString.Short.Internal`, I was able to discern that the first `Int#` is the start index and the second one is the length. The docs really should be improved though.