# IOUArray to ByteSring, as quickly as possible

Tags: arrays, haskell, websocket, ghc, bytestring

I need to mutate elements in a fixed size array of `Word8` very quickly. For this purpose I am using an `IOUArray`. I need to send this array over a websocket connection. The function `sendBinaryData` from the websockets package requires a `ByteString`. I need to convert from one representation to the other. I am using this function currently:

```
arrayToBS :: IOUArray Int Word8 -> IO (BS.ByteString)
arrayToBS = (fmap BS.pack) . getElems
```

This function converts the elements of an array to a `[Word8]` before packing that list into a bytestring, and from profiling I can see that it is quite slow. I was wondering if there a way to speed up this function, or possibly send the array over a websocket connection directly?

The array that I am using currently is:

```
size = 1000;
numBytes = size * size * 4

newBuffer :: IO (IOUArray Int Word8)
newBuffer = newArray (0, numBytes) 200 :: IO (IOUArray Int Word8)
```

and an except from the performance report:

```
COST CENTRE MODULE SRC                        %time %alloc

arrayToBS   Lib    src/Lib.hs:28:1-37          88.1   99.0
newBuffer   Lib    src/Lib.hs:(23,1)-(25,12)    9.9    0.8
```

Ideally `arrayToBS` would be much faster than creating the array. 
If I change the `size` to 100:

```
COST CENTRE         MODULE                          SRC                                                %time %alloc

arrayToBS           Lib                             src/Lib.hs:21:1-37                           100.0   86.1
mkEncodeTable.table Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal Data/ByteString/Base64/Internal.hs:105:5-75    0.0    8.0
mkEncodeTable.ix    Data.ByteString.Base64.Internal Data/ByteString/Base64/Internal.hs:104:5-43    0.0    1.1
```

Comment: Can you give an idea of what kind of performance your current solution has on what size of array?

Comment: Edited the question to provide a bit more information. Looking at the `.prof` file I can't see more information than the %time.

Comment: `IOUArray` is implemented as a [`MutableByteArray#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Data.Array.Base.html#STUArray). `ByteString` is implemented as a [`ForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/src/Data.ByteString.Internal.html#ByteString). You can copy the former to the latter using [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:copyMutableByteArrayToAddr-35-) function. This copy is the almost certainly the fastest way to do this.

Comment: @user2407038 Is there no possibility that GHC will move around the byte array? In any case, it makes sense to start by freezing the `IOUArray Word8` into a `IO (UArray Word8)` before doing this stuff...

Comment: @Alec It certainly might, but I don't see why that would be an issue. My guess is that a byte array wouldn't be moved during a copy operation anyways, but even if it were possible, I imagine that copy would be designed to deal with that. I also don't see how freezing would affect this, since `UArray` is just `ByteArray#` and those can be moved as well.

Comment: @user2407038 Apologies! I misread your comment; I hadn't realized you were proposing a full copy of the data. Ideally, one should be able to do this with only some unsafe pointer hacks (and no copying)....

Comment: @Alec Indeed, that would be ideal, but I don't think it's possible. The problem being, like you've said, is that arrays can be moved. (However, the inverse - i.e. `ByteString -> ForeignPtr Word8` [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908880/is-there-any-hope-to-cast-foreignptr-to-bytearray-for-a-function-bytestring)). I'm fairly sure (after a cursory glance at the source code) that `IOUArray` are not pinned arrays, and I'm also fairly sure that an unpinned array can't be converted to a pinned one (without a copy, which of course brings us back to the original problem).

Comment: Looking at `copyMutableByteArrayToAddr#`... Any idea what the two `#Int` parameters are?

Comment: @felixgb The first `Int#` is the offset in the source `MutableByteArray#` and the second is the number of bytes to copy. This is just an educated guess based on the more descriptive docs of [`copyMutableArray#`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.1.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#v:copyMutableArray-35-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm not very familiar with these low level primitives so this might be unsafe in some cases.

---

You will at the very least need to copy the data over once since, as @user2407038 remarks, the underlying data stored in an `IOUArray` is an unpinned array, so we can't count on GHC not moving the array around. The reverse direction (`ByteString` to `IOArray`) is however possible without a copy.

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples, MagicHash #-}

import Data.ByteString.Internal (ByteString(..))
import Data.Array.IO.Internals  (IOUArray(..))
import Data.Array.Base          (STUArray(..))
import Data.Word                (Word8)

import Foreign.ForeignPtr (mallocForeignPtrBytes, withForeignPtr)
import GHC.IO             (IO(..))
import GHC.Exts           (copyMutableByteArrayToAddr#, Ptr(..), Int(..))

arrayToBS :: IOUArray Int Word8 -> IO ByteString
arrayToBS (IOUArray (STUArray _ _ n@(I# n') mutByteArr)) = do
  bytes <- mallocForeignPtrBytes n
  withForeignPtr bytes $ \(Ptr addr) -> IO $ \state ->
    (# copyMutableByteArrayToAddr# mutByteArr 0# addr n' state, () #)
  pure (PS bytes 0 n)
```

Here is a test of this working (remember that the ascii code for `'A'` is `65`):

```
ghci> iou <- newListArray (-2,9) [65,67..] :: IO (IOUArray Int Word8)
ghci> arrayToBS iou
"ACEGIKMOQSUW"
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. This is also much faster than the method that I answered with.

Comment: @felixgb I'm not surprised, but I am curious: by how much? Also, note that you probably shouldn't throw around `realWorld#` since it often means part of your computation can be inadvertently optimized away by the compiler!

Comment: Results are at the bottom of my answer. To be honest, I don't really know what `realWorld#` is-- I'm not an experienced Haskeller and totally unaware of the internals!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to user2407038 I have *something* (Note that I have never played with primitives or unboxed types before):

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Word
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Data.ByteString.Internal
import GHC.Prim
import GHC.Exts
import GHC.ForeignPtr

bs2Addr# :: BS.ByteString -> Addr#
bs2Addr# (PS fptr offset len) = case fptr of
  (ForeignPtr addr _ ) -> addr

arrayPrim (STUArray _ _ _ x) = x

unbox :: Int -> Int#
unbox (I# n#) = n#

copy :: Int -> IO BS.ByteString
copy len = do
  -- Get the length as unboxed
  let len# = unbox len

  -- Bytestring to copy to, filled with 0s initially
  let bs = BS.pack (replicate len 0)

  -- Create a new STUArray. I don't know why it needs to be length * 2.
  arr <- stToIO (newArray (0, len * 2) 255 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Word8))

  -- MutableByteArray#
  let mArrPrim = arrayPrim arr

  -- Addr#
  let addr = bs2Addr# bs

  -- I don't know what the 2nd and 4th Int# arguments are suppose to be.
  let _ = copyMutableByteArrayToAddr# mArrPrim len# addr len# realWorld#
  return bs
```

I am using `STUArray` here instead of `IOUArray` now because I couldn't find the `IOUArray` constructor.

Results of profiling this code with 4000000 element array:

```
    Sun Aug 20 20:49 2017 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       shoot-exe +RTS -N -p -RTS

    total time  =        0.05 secs   (47 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 204,067,640 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE SRC                        %time %alloc

copy.bs     Lib    src/Lib.hs:32:7-36          66.0   96.0
copy        Lib    src/Lib.hs:(27,1)-(45,11)   34.0    3.9
```

This is the code that I compared it against:

```
arrayToBS :: (STUArray s Int Word8) -> ST s (BS.ByteString)
arrayToBS = (fmap BS.pack) . getElems

slowCopy :: Int -> IO BS.ByteString
slowCopy len = do
  arr <- stToIO (newArray (0, len - 1) 255 :: ST s (STUArray s Int Word8))
  stToIO $ arrayToBS arr
```

And its profiling report:

```
    Sun Aug 20 20:48 2017 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       shoot-exe +RTS -N -p -RTS

    total time  =        0.55 secs   (548 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,604,073,872 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE SRC                        %time %alloc

arrayToBS   Lib    src/Lib.hs:48:1-37          98.2   99.7
slowCopy    Lib    src/Lib.hs:(51,1)-(53,24)    1.6    0.2
```

OK, new version is faster. They both produce the same output. However, I would still like to know what the `#Int` parameters to `copyMutableByteArrayToAddr#` and why I have to multiply the length of the array in the fast version by 2. I'll play around a bit more and update this answer if I find out.

## Update: Alec's answer

For those curious, this is the result of profiling Alec's answer:

```
    Sun Aug 20 21:13 2017 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       shoot-exe +RTS -N -p -RTS

    total time  =        0.01 secs   (7 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc =   8,067,696 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE   MODULE SRC                          %time %alloc

newBuffer     Other  src/Other.hs:23:1-33          85.7   49.6
arrayToBS.\.\ Other  src/Other.hs:19:5-69          14.3    0.0
arrayToBS     Other  src/Other.hs:(16,1)-(20,21)    0.0   49.6
```

Looks like that's the one to use.